# Page makes background picture too small when I test the responsiveness, Need help making my html page responsive with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's a link to the page so you can check out what's happening when I test the responsiveness: https://flightacademykickz.netlify.app/

The HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ThreeJS Starter</title>
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/04559eae8b7926d003f9f2e036c9e076?family=Blippo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title-container">
      <h1 class="store-title">Flight Academy Kickz</h1>
  </div>
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    <div class="links">
      <h1 class="shop-link"><a href= "https://myshoestoreexample.myshopify.com/?_ab=0&_bt=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJaVZ0ZVhOb2IyVnpkRzl5WldWNFlXMXdiR1V1YlhsemFHOXdhV1o1TG1OdmJRWTZCa1ZVIiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMS0wOS0wNFQyMjozMzowMS42ODFaIiwicHVyIjoicGVybWFuZW50X3Bhc3N3b3JkX2J5cGFzcyJ9fQ%3D%3D--f21f531b48be3aa630f348111d777e1078c2eaf9&_fd=0&_sc=1&key=9c139530b4dddb89d523c1c3327862eafcb9a88866b4f13858e8f06405dae0d1">Shop</a></h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by too small?  You don't like that the image scales to the viewport width, or that there is extra whitespace at the bottom of the page?  Either way, we will need to see some CSS, preferably in a minimal reproducible example that can be tweaked by the community to give the desired result :)  Use codepen, or better yet, embed a working example code snippet into your question.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick look at the page's code - just removing the `top: 20rem` from `class="title-container"` solved the problem. This was causing the title element overlapping and creating the whitespace at the bottom.

For vertical aligning elements better don't use fixed values on elements. Either use:

`top: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` in a relative container or flexbox to do so. That also secures responsivness.